# MOSS 2007 Powershell Export document Attributes to CSV

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, export, metadata

I have a Powershell script that technically speaking is working fine but I want to make some things more efficient. In order to export the output to a csv what i usually do is start a powershell and type ./SkriptName.ps1 > OutPutCsvFileName.csv and then proceed doing the other tasks.

I was wondering if there is a way to pipe the output more efficiently. As far as I remember doing Export-CSV and piping it that way didnt work in my previous attempts.
I do have a "similar" skript for 2010 although in that one i am creating an array and then outputting it via export-csv.

So if anyone has a suggestion on how to achieve this i'd appreciate it!

```
$siteurl = "http://sitename/";
$weburl = ""; #leave empty
$listurl = "/Listname/"; #listname
cls;
write-host ">>> STARTING at"(get-date) `n;
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Sharepoint") 

$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("$siteurl");
$web = $site.OpenWeb("$weburl");
$list = $web.GetList("$listurl");

#$ViewFields = '<FieldRef Name="Name" /><FieldRef Name="Sachbearbeiter" /><FieldRef Name="ows_Sachbearbeiter" />'
$query = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.RowLimit = 1000; # only read 1000 items at a time into memory. Decrease this if you run into memory issues, or increase for a slight speed gain
$query.ViewFields= ""; #or use $ViewFields instead
$query.ViewAttributes += " Scope='Recursive'"; # this is where we make the query disregard folders
$index = 1;

do {
    $itemcoll = $list.GetItems($query);

    foreach ($item in $itemcoll) {

        #write-host $($item.Url) $($item["Sachbearbeiter"]);
        $SB = $item["Val1"];
        $GUID = $item["GUID"];
        write-output "$($item.UniqueId)|$SB|$GUID|$($item.url)";
    }  
    $query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $itemcoll.ListItemCollectionPosition;
    $index++;
} while ($query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null);

write-host ">>> FINISHED at"(get-date) `n;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `write-output` instead and redirect to a file ( > OutPutCsvFileName.csv or pipe to `out-file` OutPutCsvFileName.csv)

Comment: Won't work unfortunately, if i use "| out-file" after the "}" it will tell me that i cannot pipe empty values or somethign along those lines.
If i write | out-file filename.csv after the write-output "$($item....." then it will keep overwriting the file for every time the loop is executed.

Comment: Nevermind used the -append flag.